# How to get all the items belonging to a group where some items of this group satisfy a condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm getting started to SQL and PostgreSQL and I have this question:

How can I get all the items from a group where just some items satisfy a condition?

For example:

```
+________________________+
|id| group_id |    name  |
+------------------------+
| 1|     1    |   FOOD   |
--------------------------
| 2|     1    |   SNACK  |
--------------------------
| 3|     2    |   SODA   |
--------------------------
| 4|     1    |CHOCOLATE |
--------------------------

SELECT id FROM table WHERE any in group_id name LIKE 'FOOD%'
```

I'd like to retrieve 1,2,4 since they belong to group_id where one of the items is LIKE 'FOOD%'.

I cannot retrieve them through group_id since I have different databases where group_id changes, and sometimes the group_id of my interest is 1,2... The only thing that is the same in all the DBs is the fact that I'm interested in the group_id where name LIKE 'FOOD%'.

Comment: Since it seems the answers given successfully solved your issue please accept one.Accepting the answer aids future questioners that have the same issue. Please do not leave Active a satisfactory  answered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the `group_id`s that you need in the results with:

```
SELECT group_id FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE 'FOOD%'
```

Use it in your query with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE 'FOOD%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exits (select 1
             from t t2
             where t2.group_id = t.group_id and t2.name like 'FOOD%'
            );
```

You might also find it convenient to combine all the foods on a single row per group:

```
select group_id,
       array_agg(name order by name)
from t
group by group_id
having count(*) filter (where name like 'FOOD%') > 0;
```